# Using breadth first search on NetworkX to find predecessors only return 1 predecessor for each node

Tags: python, graph, networkx, breadth-first-search

I want to find all the direct predecessors of all nodes in a graph using NetworkX's [breadth first search](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_predecessors.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_predecessors). Below is my code and the graph image:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nodes = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
G = nx.DiGraph(name='G')
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
edges = [('0','1'),('2','1'),('5','4'),('1','3'),('3','4')]
G.add_edges_from(edges)

bfs = nx.bfs_predecessors(G, source='0')
bfs = dict(bfs)
nx.draw(G, font_weight='bold', with_labels=True)
plt.show()
plt.savefig('graph.png')
print(bfs)
```

[image]

The above code returns `{'1': '0', '3': '1', '4': '3'}`. 
I'm expecting for node "1" the predecessors are "0" and "2", for node "4" they are "5" and "3". Why did I only get 1 predecessor for each node?

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a directed graph, and the BFS respects the directions: it only explores outgoing arcs. While there is an incoming arc to node 1 from node 2 in the digraph, the BFS starting from node 0 cannot figure this out, because it follows only outgoing arcs and the arc 1->2 is not outgoing from node 1.

If you start the BFS from node 2 you will find that it will report 2 as a predecessor of 1, but it will **not** report 0 as a predecessor of 1. If you start the BFS from node 4 you will find that it won't report any predecessors at all. This is because there is no way to go **out** from node 4, so the BFS will start and end at node 4.

Comment: Is there any solution to get the results I'm expecting? Thank you

Comment: You could run the BFS repeatedly from unvisited nodes, till every node is visited. Then you can take the union of the predecessors reported for each node by these different BFS invocations.